# Daemon cron not work

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to use the deamon cron to add a command but didn't work.
I open the file /etc/crontab and I add the following sentence:
   30 16 * * 1 root poweroff
But my system doesn't close. Please help me, I don't kow what I am doing bad.

Comment: How do you open `/etc/crontab`? You *must* use `crontab -e`; you *cannot* just edit the crontab with any editor. Second, always specify the full path to the binary you want to run, and don't assume any environment variables are set. Check that you can normally run `poweroff`;if that doesn't work, it won't work from the crontab either. Make sure your cron daemon accepts the user name (or what is `root` supposed to be?) in the crontab. Run `man crontab`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, I would try the following...

```
sudo -i 
crontab -e
```

Add the next line

```
30 16 * * 1 /sbin/poweroff
```

[poweroff](https://linux.die.net/man/8/poweroff)